# resolve one host differently on windows server session

Tags: remote-desktop, hosts-file, windows-server

I want to temporarily (=resets after disconnect) resolve a host differently for (only) my connected session (via RDP) on a windows server machine.

Can this be done? Something like a termporary hosts-file change for only one user?

Example: Until disconnect, for only this RDP session:

```
google.com => resolve to localhost
```

Comment: It's not quite clear. Please give an example of what you're want to do.

Comment: tried to clear up, wasn't worded well, mea culpa

Comment: I'm also interested not doing this system/user-environment wide but application specific

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible approaches:

- Replace `hosts` file (as you suggested).
- Configure additional DNS server and substitute it for this session.

Both approaches has a major drawback - in case if something will go wrong the modified `hosts`/alternative DNS will be affecting other sessions and users.

And these methods aren't suitable for a multi-user environment.

The only user-specific method I could think is some AV/Firewall solution with a DNS filtering functionality.